# Okta auth stuck in infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, owin, okta

I'm tasked to setup authentication by Okta. The auth code works on my dev computer, but it gets infinite loop on the staging server.

The framework is asp.net webforms 4.8

Infinite loop:
[image]

When I look into the system log, there are only 3 entries, no error:
[image]

Here's Okta settings in Web.Config, I have double checked the "okta:RedirectUri" and "okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri" match the values in the Okta developer dashboard settings (also shown below):

```
    <!-- OKTA: -->
    <!-- 1. Replace these values with your Okta configuration -->
    <add key="okta:ClientId" value="************" />
    <add key="okta:ClientSecret" value="*******************" />
    <add key="okta:OktaDomain" value="https://dev-*****.okta.com" />
    <add key="okta:AuthorizationServerId" value="default" />
    <!-- 2. Update the Okta application with these values -->
    <add key="okta:RedirectUri" value="https://www.company-url.com/subdomain/default.aspx" />
    <add key="okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://www.company-url.com/subdomain" />
```

In the Okta developer dashboard -> applications -> Test App -> General -> General Settings: the sign-in redirect URI is:
https://www.company-url.com/subdomain/default.aspx

The sign-out redirect URI is
https://www.company-url.com/subdomain

[image]

Also on the dashboard -> Security -> API -> Trusted Origins, the URL "https://www.company-url.com" was added to allow both CORS and Redirect

The StartUp class (vb.net):

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Okta.AspNet
Imports Owin

<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(Company.Startup))>

Public Class Startup
        Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
                .LoginPath = New PathString("/Login.aspx")
            })
            app.UseOktaMvc(New OktaMvcOptions() With {
                .OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:OktaDomain"),
                .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:ClientId"),
                .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:ClientSecret"),
                .AuthorizationServerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:AuthorizationServerId"),
                .RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:RedirectUri"),
                .PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"),
                .Scope = New List(Of String) From {
                    "openid",
                    "profile",
                    "email"
                },
                .LoginMode = LoginMode.SelfHosted
            })
        End Sub
    End Class
```

The Login.aspx markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Illinois.Login" %>

<script src="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/5.2.0/js/okta-sign-in.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/5.2.0/css/okta-sign-in.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="include/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>


<div id="widget"></div>

<form method="POST" action="Login.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionToken" id="hiddenSessionTokenField" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var oktaDomain = '<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:oktaDomain").ToString() %>';

    var signIn = new OktaSignIn({
        baseUrl: oktaDomain
    });

    signIn.renderEl({ el: '#widget' }, (res) => {
        var sessionTokenField = $("#hiddenSessionTokenField");
        sessionTokenField.val(res.session.token);
        var form = sessionTokenField.parent();
        form.submit();
    }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        });
</script>
```

And the Login.aspx.vb code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect

Partial Public Class Login
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            If Request.RequestType = "POST" AndAlso Not Request.IsAuthenticated Then
                Dim claimsPrincipal As ClaimsPrincipal = TryCast(Page.User, ClaimsPrincipal)
                Dim sessionToken As String = Request.Form("sessionToken")?.ToString()
                Dim properties As AuthenticationProperties = New AuthenticationProperties()
                properties.Dictionary.Add("sessionToken", sessionToken)
                properties.RedirectUri = "/"
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Please help to see which part was not configured correctly. Any help is appreciated. Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on what exactly you mean by _infinite loop_?  Eye balling the code you've supplied, there appear to be no loops (infinite or not).  Is it more the more the UI is getting in some unexpected loop trying to authenticate?  Have you considered cookie permissions?

Comment: @Hursey My apologize for not being clear. By "Infinite loop" I meant the little spinning circle on top of the first screenshot would just keep spinning. It never redirected me to the "Redirect URL".

Comment: Is the staging and dev machines on the same network?  It's not something like firewalls interrupting the callbacks?

Comment: @Hursey it's not in the same network but the staging machine is open to all IPs for SSL connections. So it's unlikely a firewall problem.